# in app purchase always gives an error message in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have implemented in app purchase in my application.On clicking the buy button it will asks for the confirmation.But after clicking ok,it always shows an error message saying "You have already purchased this but it hasn't been downloaded.Tap ok to download it now." Nothing happens after this.In the

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{}
```

it always call the case "SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:".itried to print the error and it says "unable to connect to itunes store".What i have done is,on clicking the buy button,calls this method:

```
`- (void) requestProductData
{
    NSLog(@"requestProductData");
    SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: 
                                 [NSSet setWithObjects:featureBusiness , nil]] ; // add any other product here
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(beginAnimationPurchased)]) {
        [delegate beginAnimationPurchased];
    }
}
`
```

can anyone guide me?thanks in advance.

Comment: Create another test id and check inapp purchase.

Comment: Is this a consumable or non-consumable purchase?

Comment: @Madhumitha i have created another test account but getting the same alert message.

Comment: @WendiKidd actually i got the id from the client and i am not sure about it.Can i confirm it anyway?

Comment: in this method - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
 [purchasableObjects addObjectsFromArray:response.products];
 } i am getting the product details in the array.but after it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was using the IAPHelper code from the Ray Wenderlich example, which I then subclassed into my own MyAppIAPHelper.  I resolved this particular problem by declaring an observer at the top of my main view controller 'm' file:

```
IAPHelper *observer;
```

then adding a transaction observer in the ViewDidLoad of my main view controller:

```
observer = [[IAPHelper alloc] init];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];
```

In my dealloc, I added:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:observer];
```

Not sure this is the best solution, but it worked for me. Hope this helps :-)